# How can I configure Spring Roo to replace Log4j with SLf4J and Logback as the default logging libraries?

Tags: java, log4j, spring-roo, logback

How can I configure [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) to replace [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as the default logging libraries?

Answer (score 1):

This [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-590) issue would seem to suggest that this is not yet possible.